# Does the Mac App Store allow subclassing private methods?

Tags: objective-c, subclass, mac-app-store, private-methods

The Mac App Store guidelines state:

> Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected

Does that include sub-classing public objects with methods that aren't mentioned in their class' reference?

Comment: This is a question for Apple, not SO.

Comment: I would guess not, have you read their docs?

Comment: I've read the Mac App Store Review Guidelines and all it says about private APIs is the line mentioned in this question.

Comment: Now I'm curious. Do you have an example of a class where this would be the case?

Comment: When NSTableView's `allowsColumnSelection` is disabled, it doesn't call NSTableHeaderCell `highlight:withFrame:inView:`. According to http://parmanoir.com/Debugging_with_Activity_Monitor it calls `_drawThemeContents:highlighted:inView:` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has not been entirely consistent in this regard, but they have rejected some apps for this.

Comment: I know the usual quality of your answers, so no disrespect meant, but... no citation nor explanation?

Comment: @Yar: No offense taken. I don't remember why I didn't include any links. Probably I meant to add them when I got time to track down the scattered articles I've read and just forgot. I still vaguely remember the details, so I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend against it. You don't know if Apple will reject your app for it (so you have to go back and fix it), or if they will change the private method (maybe it won't exist in the future so your apps won't work as expected on future OS X versions (this applies to iOS as well), and then you will have to go back and fix it).

Either way, whether they approve or reject your app, it's a bad idea.

What are you trying to do exactly anyway? Maybe there is a better and safer way to do it.

Comment: The OP does not suggest that he is calling any private methods. It sounds like he is asking about if you are breaking rules by sub classing as a subclass inherits all the functionality from the parent including private methods. No where does he mention actually calling a private method

Comment: Indeed, I'm trying to do what @Paul said. More specifically, when NSTableView's `allowsColumnSelection` is disabled, it doesn't call NSTableHeaderCell `highlight:withFrame:inView:`. According to http://parmanoir.com/Debugging_with_Activity_Monitor it calls `_drawThemeContents:highlighted:inView:` instead.

Comment: @JG566 assuming that "using" means SENDING a message as opposed to getting in the way of a received message is pretty lawyerly. I think it's definitely rejectable. I think the interesting question -- which no one will even entertain -- is whether their automatic app checker thingee would detect it or not ;)

Comment: @Roberto - Why are you bringing up iOS? This question specifically pertained to OS X.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare - I updated my answer to say OS X, but the same applies to iOS.

Comment: @Paul.s - Fair enough. It is still a bad idea to subclass a private method. You never know when it is going to change.

Answer (score -1):

Almost all (but the simplest) well designed object's will have have private API's. That is the whole idea of encapsulation.

My guess is that when you sub-class a framework class, your code is stil only calling the public API on that class therefore you are not yourself calling any private API's. If this was not the case then surely no one would be able to release any software using the Cocoa and Cocoa-touch frameworks.

If you subclass and deliberately call a private method then of course this would be a violation

Take this example

```
/*
 * This is a framework class that needs to be subclassed
 * it has one public method  - (void)save;
 * and one private method    - (void)doSomeWork;
 */
@interface FrameWorkClass : NSObject

- (void)save;

@end

@interface FrameWorkClass ()

//private 
- (void)doSomeWork;

@end

@implementation FrameWorkClass

- (void)save
{
  [self doSomeWork]; // Call to private method
}

@end

/*
 * This is our subclass of FrameWorkClass
 */
@interface MyClass : FrameWorkClass
// more methods
@end
```

If I do this

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myClass save];
```

the save method results in the private API method `- (void)doSomeWork;` being called. I did not call it directly the framework class did. If I had done this instead

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myClass doSomeWork];
```

Then I would be calling the private API directly which would be declined.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. I'd subclass FrameWorkClass' `doSomeWork` because it gets called from `save`. (`save` would be a method not written by me, but a public one by Apple that calls the private method `doSomeWork`)

Comment: So you want to override a private API - this will most likely be cause for rejection. You will need to think the problem through more thoroughly to avoid doing this. As stated by @roberto this would be unreliable anyway